# Rendering JQPlot through PHP

Tags: php, jquery, charts, jqplot

I have a page which generates HTML dynamically and does an echo of it. How can I do this with the JQPlot. I can have multiple graphs on same page. I see that JQPlot uses document.ready to render it. I will generate required arrays from php .

How should I do this so that I can just call a PHP/Javascript method / include and pass required parameters to display chart?

If I have multiple charts should I put a document.ready and than out a PHP
for loop inside it and call a generic plot function where I can pass
all my parameters ?

something as below

```
$(document).ready{function(){
   <?php for loop to generate required objects for chart  ?>
  Call JQPlot function to generate chart
   <? >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php's json_encode to generate a javascript object in your javascript tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = <?php echo json_encode($phpdata)?>
   ...
   ... process data with jqPlot, now it's in a js variable.
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like the following in php if you use the agiletoolkit php framework.

```
$chart = $p->add('jqplot', null, null);
$arr=array(array(11,123,1236, 'Acura'),array(45,92,1067, 'Alfa Romeo'),
    array(24,104,1176, 'AM General'),array(50,23,610, 'Aston Martin Lagonda'),
    array(18,17,539, 'Audi'), array(7,89,864,'BMW'),   
    array(2,13,1026,'Bugatti'));
$chart->setSeries(array($arr));
$chart->set('seriesDefaults',array('renderer'=>'BubbleRenderer',
    'rendererOptions'=>array('bubbleGradients'=>true), 'shadow'=>true));
```

which will create a graph like this

[image]

Have a look at my website for more [examples of creating graphs with php](http://sterlingend.co.uk).